# idle time period between group of records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i am going to get idle and running time period of a car using mysql.here my table

### speed(kmph) |  cdate

00.00  | *2014-08-11 00:00:01*
00.00  | 2014-08-11 01:01:01
00.00  | 2014-08-11 03:03:41
00.00  | 2014-08-11 05:01:01
00.00  | *2014-08-11 08:20:01*
**50.88 |  2014-08-11 08:20:02

100.88  | 2014-08-11 09:40:22**
00.00  | *2014-08-11 10:20:23*
00.00  | 2014-08-11 11:10:33
00.00  | *2014-08-11 13:30:56*
**50.88 |   2014-08-11 13:30:57

100.88 | 2014-08-11 15:10:22**

what i need is,

the idle time of the car is

2014-08-11 00:00:01 to 2014-08-11 08:20:01
2014-08-11 10:20:23 to 2014-08-11 13:30:56

i have to get these result from mysql table .

please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning a grouping variable to each row of idle periods.  The easiest is simply the number of non-zero speeds before any given record (that has a speed of 0).  Then do the aggregation:

```
select min(cdate), max(cdate)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table t2
              where t2.cdate <= t.cdate and t2.speed > 0
             ) as grp
      from table t
      where t.speed = 0
     ) x
group by grp;
```

Comment: your answer nearly reached what i want.but the car's idle end time should be the starting time of the car...

Comment: The time span is defined by the period when the speed is 0, just as in the example data in the question.